# UnsafeMutablePointer to an Array element

Tags: ios, swift, macos, unsafemutablepointer

```
var a = [1,2,3]
let ptr1 = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>(&a[0]) //works fine

let index = 0
let ptr2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>(&a[index]) //compiler throws error
```

> error: cannot invoke initializer for type `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>` with an argument list of type `(inout Int)`

Why the latter one doesn't compile? Is there anything I am missing here?

---

I wanted to do like a below snippet.

```
class Holder {
    var numbers: [Int] = [1,2,3,4]
    var modifier: Modifier

    init(index: Int) {
       self.modifier = Modifier(UnsafeMutablePointer(&self.numbers) + index)
    }

}

class Modifer {
  var ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>

  init(_ ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) {
     self.ptr = ptr
  }

  func change(to: Int) {
     self.ptr.pointee = to
    // expected the change to be reflected in numbers array
    // but as Rob Napier said it became invalid and throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS
  }
}
```

How can I achieve the above expected result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that neither of these is a valid way to create an UnsafeMutablePointer. Swift is free to deallocate a immediately after the last time it is referenced, so by the time you use these pointers, they may be invalid. The tool you want is `a.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer`.

That said, the correct syntax here is:

```
let ptr2 = UnsafeMutablePointer(&a) + index
```

---

Looking at your updated code, there's no way for this to make sense on Array. I think you're assuming that Arrays are reference types. They're value types. There's no way to change a piece of `numbers`. Any change to it replaces the entire array with a completely different array. Swift has some clever copy-on-write tricks to make this efficient, and in practice it may not *actually* replace the entire array, but you should program as though it did. You should consider the following line:

```
array[1] = 2
```

to be equivalent to:

```
array = <a new array that is identical, but element 1 has been replaced by 2>
```

This means that pointers into `Array` are meaningless outside of very controlled situations (such as inside a `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer` block).

What you want is something more like this:

```
class Holder {
    var numbers: [Int] = [1,2,3,4]
    private(set) var modifier: ((Int) -> ())! // ! is an artifact of capturing self in init

    init(index: Int) {
        self.modifier = { [weak self] in self?.numbers[index] = $0 }
    }
}

let holder = Holder(index: 2)
holder.numbers  // [1, 2, 3, 4]
holder.modifier(0)
holder.numbers  // [1, 2, 0, 4]
```

Comment: How to use `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer`? When I try it throws error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'a' is immutable.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the contents. Inside the block, you have to use the buffer pointer provided. You can't access `a` directly. What's the goal?

Comment: I have updated the question to minimally describe what I actually tried to achieve. In my original case the numbers array is a array of structs

Comment: Updated the answer. You don't want pointers for this. You want closures.